# Python PDF generation - image from internet

Tags: python, image, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a python pdf generator that can use an image directly from a given url? Right now I'm using ReportLab and I have to download and save the image to a file and then using filename I can add it to the PDF. Which is significatly slower I imagine, in comparison to directly downloading the image, storing it in memory somehow and write to the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really cannot see how this is significantly slower.
The local disks bandwidth should be much larger than the internet bandwidth.
So the extra local save/load times should be extremely low overhead.

If you really wan't to speed stuff up, check if the file already exists locally before downloading.

unless of course if you are doing this download manually?

Comment: Of course I'm not :D And the files never exist because I want to generate the pdf and not keep have any of the downloaded files on the computer, therefore I delete them immediately after using in the PDF. So you're confident that it's not a noticeable difference in time?

Comment: As with all optimizations, you should first check if this is really a significant performance bottleneck. My guess would be that, as Henrik said, you will find that the extra disk write+read are insignificant compared to the file download.

Comment: @Greyshack yes I am sure. If the extra overhead of using the hdd makes a siginificant difference, you would IMHO need another hdd setup. - But, it's actually quite easy to test, if you have enough RAM available. Simply download and save it to a ramdisk instead of a physical disk, before creating the pdf. It's a well known linux feature, but it can be achieved in windows also. Example: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/